# Javascript- Passing variable as method

Tags: javascript, variables, methods

My issue is trying to pass a variable defined via prompt into an object method. At the end of my code I try to pass variable "house" into the ".teamPick" method in my class constructor but no-go. If I console.log(house) it prints 'gryffindor' but when I try to pass house.teamPick() I get an error saying "house.teamPick() is not a function." I am at my wit's end.

```
function House(color,broom) {
    this.color= color;
    this.broom= broom;
    this.teamPick= function() {
        alert("Throw on your"+" "+ this.color + " " + "robes, jump on your \n" + this.broom + ", " + "and let's play some Quidditch!")
    };
};

var gryffindor= new House('red', 'Firebolt');

var house= prompt('What team do you choose?').toLowerCase(); 

if(house=== "gryffindor") {
    house.teamPick();
};
```

Comment: Try `gryffindor.teamPick()`? Or `window[house].teamPick()`

Comment: `house` is a string.  Why would it have a `.teamPick` method?

Comment: Gerrit(), window[house].teamPick() worked like a charm. Thank you for that. Now I am going to go try and research why it worked as I have never seen window before.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong value (`house`) at the end of your script. `house` is a string value and not an instance of `House`.

`gryffindor` is an instance of `House` (created with `new House()`), so that's what you want to use instead.

You want the last three lines to be something like this:

```
if(house === "gryffindor") {
    gryffindor.teamPick();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your what you suggested does work if I just use one instance of house (this example being gryffindor), but in my full code I have 4 house objects built and I am trying to write just one line of code that will fill in which house the user selects and then run .teamPick. I could just write a big if/else if statement with all 4 possibilities but I am trying not to repeat code as much as possible.